# starting tomcat servelt engine tomcat8 [fail ] inside container

Tags: image, shell, docker, build, containers

hello everyone i wrote a script which must install apache guacamole then i launched the script on my ubuntu 18.04 machine all worked fine. I now want to re-use my script but rather in a docker container for cella I have created a dockerfile which takes my script into account.

here is my dockerfile.

[image: Dockerfile]

here is my script :

part I

[image: script part I]

part II

[image: script part II]

part III

[image: script part III]

part IV

[image: script part IV]

part V

[image: script part V]

and here is the error message that I have at the end you can notice all the error starting **tomcat servelt engine tomcat8 [fail]** on the last line

[image: error]

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Please copy-paste all the relevant information as text in your post and not as screenshots. It would make it easier for people to understand the problem and provide solutions

Comment: thank you for the remark but I cannot do otherwise the machine or is hosted my code is a remote terminal, which is not managed by me therefore I can provide you with information of my code only in the form of screenshot sorry

Comment: I understand. I embedded the photos in your post to make it easier for people to have all the information they need here.